# How to open an ORC File in Azure data lake?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have an ORC File in azure data lake and i am unable to preview data.when i try to view it's just showing some irrelevant junk data.Can anyone help me which tool or how to preview contents of an ORC File

Comment: Can you list the tools already tried and why they were not applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my experience, Azure Data Factory doesn't support preview the data of some specific format file, such as .xlsx file. ORC file also is not support data preview.

[image]

But Azure Data Factory support copy ORC format file from Azure Data lake. To see:

1. [Supported file formats and compression codecs in Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#orc-format)
2. [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure Data
   Factory: Other format dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#other-format-dataset).

Hope this helps.